# Using web audio api live input to control stuff

Tags: html, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I would like to use my microphone input to control an image i have. I managed to edit [this](http://www.smartjava.org/examples/webaudio/example2.html) code by far and get my image affected. There was javascriptNode.onaudioprocess = function() and for some reason it disabled my microphone input checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need a Javascript node at all.  You should just use a requestAnimationFrame handler to do the section of your code that does:

```
        var array =  new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
        analyser.getByteFrequencyData(array);
        var average = getAverageVolume(array);
        var array2 =  new Uint8Array(analyser2.frequencyBinCount);
        analyser2.getByteFrequencyData(array2);
        var average2 = getAverageVolume2(array2);
        element.style.opacity = average/100;
        element2.style.opacity = average2/100;
```